# how can I redirect to a JSP from other JSP in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

Hello friends how can I redirect to a JSP from other JSP ? 
I want to show a pdf in the browser (I have programmed the pdf in the last JSP but with the dispatcher that I use it to redirect the last jsp , the name of the last jsp doesn't appear in the browser, and I need that the name of the last JSP appears in the browser.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.sendRedirect()`, or if you want to open a pop up window, just use `window.open()` and pass the `URL` of JSP in the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the name to appear you will need to use a client-side redirect rather than a dispatcher.